# Selenium Webdriver: How to wait until document.readyState set to 'complete'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver in my code to run Firefox instance, and I have some timing issues.
Seems that my code starts to run before the page fully loaded.

How can I stop the code execution until my Webdriver instance loads the whole page?

example of my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://google.com')
example_result = browser.execute_script('some_script')
```

In this example, the example_result will be set before the page fully loaded.
How can I wait until the page readyState will change to "complete"?